# Adding the tag to a ARC enabled project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

In a ARC enabled project, is there a way to add the `-fno-objc-arc` tag programatically in the code it self.

So i could give my source files to someone else, and that person need not add the `-fno-objc-arc` manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume this is because you want to distribute your project as a re-usable library that can be used in other projects regardless of whether they use ARC?

I don't think you can add the flag to the source to tell ARC to ignore the file (at least I've not found a way yet), but you can detect if ARC is enabled within the file using

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
...
#endif
```

You could use this to raise a warning, by saying

```
#warning This file is not ARC compatible, add the -fno-objc-arc tag
```

But an even more elegant solution is to use this feature to automatically branch your code at compile time so that it works on both ARC and non-ARC builds.

I wrote a simple re-usable header that can be pasted into the top of your source file or included in the project as a standalone header file:

https://gist.github.com/1563325

This provides a bunch of macros to use instead of retain, release and autorelease methods so that they can be automatically stripped for ARC builds. For an example of how this is used, check out iRate:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate/tree/master/iRate

It only takes a few minutes to convert a class file this way.

Comment: Could you maybe do something with `__atribute__((target("tell-the-linker-something"))`? I messed around for a bit and didn't find anything that worked, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: So i will have to paste the content of ARCHelper.h to all my non-ARC .h files ?

Comment: If you don't need the weak linking module it's only about 10 lines and you can also put it in the .m file where it's less obtrusive. Alternatively, you could just add it as a single .h file to your project instead of copying and pasting it into every file. You could also just take a look at how it works and replicate the bits you want, which may only be 5 lines or so - I only made a library so I could re-use it without needing to think about it again every time.

Comment: To be clear, this isn't just for use in non-ARC files, it's for using to convert ARC or non-ARC files into files that will work in both environments. It won't magically make your file work in both environments, you'll still need to replace your retain/release and autorelease statements with the macros provided by the library.

Answer (score 1):

No - not in the code itself.  This is stored in your project file, so if you send the entire project to someone else it should work.  However, you can't just send them a few classes and have that work (it needs to be the entire project).

Comment: as @nick lockwood said we can check arc compatibility at compiletime. And also can generate warning or error. Also we can add non-arc code like
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
//@autoreleasepool{   etc
#else
//release retain autoreleasepool etc
#endif